# Make components out of number: best practices to format

Tags: ios, uikit, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView to enter a weight in kg. It allows entering the weight from 0.0 to 299.9 kg.

For the sake of convenience, I configured the picker with three components, one for the hundreds (0 - 2), one for the tens (0 - 99) and finally one for the fraction of one kilo (.0 to .9). I wonder what the best practice for back and forth converting the input of the component to a simple float or NSNumber is.

I am aware that I could simply save all three values independently, but I figure that there must be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 4):

```
-(void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
 NSInteger hundreds = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] * 100;
 NSInteger tens = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1] * 10;
 float oneTenth = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2] * 0.1f;

 NSNumber *total = @(hundreds+tens+oneTenth);
}
```

You can do what you want with total :)

Comment: Thanks, that's a down to earth approach. BTW, the tens do not need to be multiplied. Maybe my terminology is misleading here.